# What can cause Oracle to ignore an APPEND hint requesting it to perform a direct path load?

Tags: oracle, insert, oracle10g, hint

I wish to do a serial, logging insert of bulk data from one table to another.  This is once-of as part of a data migration so swapping partitions, etc is not an answer.

The SQL will be of the following structure:

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ ... SELECT FROM ....
```

What might cause Oracle to run this a convential insert rather than a direct path insert?

For example, I believe having a trigger on the table will cause Oracle to conduct a convential insert.  Is there a definitive list of restrictions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quote from  http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1211797200346279484 :

"insert /*+ append */ will ignore the append hint and use conventional path loading when the table has referential integrity or a trigger..." - Tom Kyte

From https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/statements_9014.htm#sthref6486

> Direct-path INSERT is subject to a number of restrictions. If any of
>   these restrictions is violated, then Oracle Database executes
>   conventional INSERT serially without returning any message, unless
>   otherwise noted:
>
> - You can have multiple direct-path INSERT statements in a single transaction, with or without other DML statements. However, after one
>     DML statement alters a particular table, partition, or index, no other
>     DML statement in the transaction can access that table, partition, or
>     index.
> - Queries that access the same table, partition, or index are allowed before the direct-path INSERT statement, but not after it.
> - If any serial or parallel statement attempts to access a table that has already been modified by a direct-path INSERT in the same
>     transaction, then the database returns an error and rejects the
>     statement.
> - The target table cannot be of a cluster.
> - The target table cannot contain object type columns.
> - Direct-path INSERT is not supported for an index-organized table (IOT) if it is not partitioned, if it has a mapping table, or if it is
>     reference by a materialized view.
> - Direct-path INSERT into a single partition of an index-organized table (IOT), or into a partitioned IOT with only one partition, will
>     be done serially, even if the IOT was created in parallel mode or you
>     specify the APPEND or APPEND_VALUES hint. However, direct-path INSERT
>     operations into a partitioned IOT will honor parallel mode as long as
>     the partition-extended name is not used and the IOT has more than one
>     partition.
> - The target table cannot have any triggers or referential integrity constraints defined on it.
> - The target table cannot be replicated.
> - A transaction containing a direct-path INSERT statement cannot be or become distributed.

However the list in the manual is not exhaustive and is not completely accurate.  For example, [referential integrity constraints do not block direct-path INSERT if that constraint is part of reference partitioning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23330143/409172).

Comment: Tom gives those as examples so that's a good source, but I wonder if there are any other possibilities. e.g. DEFAULT SYSDATE.  Of course I can experiment, but I'd rather find a documented answer.

Comment: you can find the restrictions here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF01604 under "Conventional and Direct-Path INSERT"

Comment: Thanks - that's what I was missing.  Maybe edit that into your answer as it's better than the Tom Kyte link.